# Gimp - Mouse wheel scroll is not recognized: no zoom and no scroll

Tags: linux, mouse, scrolling, gimp, zoom

**The problem:**

The mouse wheel scroll events don't seem to be recognized by Gimp: There is no scroll, and there is no zoom in or out when using the mouse wheel, either with or without the CTRL key.

**Some useful context:** It used to work normally in the same system (Xubuntu 22.04), same version (Gimp 2.10.34). I have already thoroughly confirmed that this does not have anything to do with the mouse hardware, which works Ok in every other programs like e.g. Krita. It is clear that the scroll events are there: Gimp just doesn't "see" them, no matter what mouse is being used.

The **expected behaviour** in Gimp, and since many years of use, by default (or if and when *properly configured* it to do something like that) is:

1. the mouse wheel scrolls up and down the view of the edited image as it happens in e.g. a browser, and
2. if the shift key is hold simultaneously while scrolling up or down, then the contents scrolls left or right, and
3. if the control key is hold while scrolling up or down, then the image being edited is zoomed in or out.

**What actually happens**: for unknown reasons, scrolling the wheel doesn't generate any action in Gimp: no scroll, and no zoom with or without holding any modifier key.

**What has been done:**

I have tried the most obvious steps without success. The first thing to do, is to do the official procedure to correctly configure the Input devices in Preferences -> Input devices, and in Preferences -> Input controllers -> Main Mouse Wheel, and configure the proper controller event action for each event (Scroll down, Scroll up, Scroll down + ctrl, and Scroll up + ctrl).
I have done that carefully and triple checked with all the Gimp documentation, plus years of user experience, plus many tutorials and how-to's, plus I have also another computer where this problem is not happening.
So my question is *not* how to configure the wheel behavior: that is done.

How can I test whether the wheel scroll events are "seen" by Gimp and why would those somehow not trigger the configured actions?

---

Gimp version: 2.10.34; in Xubuntu 22.04 LTS (thus Xfce 4.16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of work and experimentation, I have a solution.

As stated earlier, it's not about how to configure the wheel behaviour: it's about how we set the **mode** of the various devices. Essentially: do not set to "Screen" mode the **`Virtual core XTEST pointer`** and certain other devices. Since there are so many different devices, I wanted to try and write a solution that is not specific to my context and hardware.

So I'll put it as a process, and explain along, so this is more general than *my* particular case and hopefully help others:

1. Edit -> Preferences -> Input Devices -> Configure Extended Input Devices
2. On the input devices pane, select `Core Pointer` and ensure it's set to **Screen mode**.
3. Set every other devices to Disabled mode. The idea is to leave it in a "clean" state. **Save** and close the dialog.

   For example, in my case:

   [image: Example of the Configure Input Devices dialog, with annotations]
4. Open an image and test just the mouse wheel for scroll and zoom. It should work as per its behaviour configuration, default or otherwise.
5. Now, test your tablet devices. In my particular case, *in this configuration everything works OK*, including my tablet (which is a Wacom tablet, behind **`OpenTabletDriver`**) and my mouse, which actually is a Kensington trackball, and it behaves as expected.
6. If you need/want to change the mode of any of your devices (which were disabled earlier), go ahead and do it, but ***do it one by one***, i.e.: change the mode of only one device, **save** it **and** test, and **only then** proceed to the next one.
   This way, once you get in trouble with one particular device, you will know better: very specially, you may find in trouble if you set `Virtual core XTEST pointer` to Screen mode.

**In general, troubles come when we set to Screen mode anything that is not a tablet device**.

But not **only** that necessarily.

In *my case*, interestingly, if I set my **`OpenTabletDriver`** devices in Screen mode, then the mouse scroll function ***fails*** again. I tested in various combinations: with the trackball in Screen or Disabled modes.  I can confirm that -again, in my case- I should set Screen mode only for the **Core Pointer**, as shown in the picture above, in order to have things as I want, which strongly suggests that the **`OpenTabletDriver`** Virtual Tablet would take control of the mouse wheel if I enable it in Screen mode, as it happens with the `Virtual core XTEST pointer`. Naturally, I am not implying that other driver and devices will have the same behavior: this is an example.

**Final comments and advice:**

Very interestingly, I have found that these kind of troubles with Gimp are very old, and very unfortunately, there is nothing in the official documentation, including the latest manual, that mentions these simple ideas. There is [this bug from 2012](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684617), which is flagged "RESOLVED OBSOLETE", in which this problem is clearly mentioned.

I have also found some [troubleshooting tips for older versions of Gimp](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/505#note_209521), (from 9 years ago) such as renaming/deleting the Gimp configuration folder, and then start Gimp, it will create a new folder with default settings. This old technique is still useful, but needs to be updated (Gimp configuration directory is currently in `~/.config/GIMP/2.10`) and visible in official documentation.  I may be wrong, and I would be very happy if this thread can be used to highlight any relevant links or references to help the Gimp users community. Please feel free to contribute.